# Application for Managing Daily Routine?

Tags: software-recommendation, task-management

**I like to know, is there any good application that can manage a routine and remind me about every hour's task.**

I am a very forgetful person. I literally forget every small task I have to do. So, I am thinking about an application which can do things like:

- Make a list for work on a **daily basis**
- Remind me of every hour's task
- Make a progress report (optional)

I tried some task manager, but I have to plan every single task by myself. It would be very helpful if the application can make a daily routine.

Comment: Perhaps [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) is a more suitable site to ask this?

Comment: If you have an Android mobile, you use Gmail and Google calendar. You can use Google Launcher which extract info from your gmail and Google calendar so it will predicts almost 80% of the tasks for you. 
I don't know if such a program exists.

Comment: I don't have android phone. :(